# MongoDB aggregation framework query for sum time differences

Tags: json, mongodb, database-design, aggregation-framework

we have events like these:

```
{
  "dateStart": "2018-04-04T08:50:42.389Z",
  "machine": "Machine1",
  "state": "Running"
},
{
  "dateStart": "2018-04-04T09:10:00.389Z",
  "machine": "Machine1",
  "state": "Pause"
},
{
  "dateStart": "2018-04-04T09:11:00.000Z",
  "machine": "Machine1",
  "state": "Running"
},
```

What is the MongoDB query to calculate the amount of time that Machine1 was in state Running in a specific day/week/month?

is that even possible?

since we are in the design phase, we are open to suggestion on modification of the JSON schema. What is important here, is the ability to calculate sum of duration from the events.

Comment: Post here what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference between two dates using [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and using [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[Aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) comes in with a lot of [pipeline operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to get the desired result with manipulations applied on our collections.

One modification required in your case is to store the date in ISODate format as  `ISODate("2018-04-04T09:11:00.000Z")` so that you can use all arithmetic operations given in mongodb.

> Machine1 was in state Running in a specific day/week/month?

Use [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in aggregation pipeline to filter the documents in your collection which matches your criteria

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{$match:{machine:"Machine1", state:"Running"}}])
```